# Call a mysql Stored Function from PHP 5.3 application

Tags: php, mysql, stored-functions

I'm having issues calling a stored function in MYSQL DB from a PHP -v5.3.29 application.[Below is my Stored procedure in MySql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjcG8.png)

It outputs a total number of working days between two given days

Code(in PHP) to call this stored function is written below:

```
$db = dbLink();
$result = $db->query("SELECT WORKDAYS('2018-04-01','2018-04-08')");
if (!$result) {
   die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
echo '<script>';
 echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $result ) .')';
echo '</script>'
```

Problem is when I try to call this stored function from a PHP application I get returned an object with Null attributes.

I'm writing the output '$result' on web console and the screenshots are attached below. 
[$result object on web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq9GX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `$result` is just the result set. You need to actually fetch the data from the result set. If you're using mysqli, use

```
$row = $result->fetch_array();
$workdays = $row[0];
```

if you're using PDO, you can get the result directly using

```
$workdays = $result->fetchColumn();
```